# What is wrong wtih my Insertion Sort Code

Tags: python, list, insertion-sort

I am trying to write code that is an insertion sort. I am trying to get the code to take 2 values and put them into a new list while sorting it. So far it just puts the values into the list without them being sorted, i'm not quite sure why

```
 pos = 0
    pos2 = 1
    go = True
    while go == True:
        for i in range(len(ex)-1):
            stack.append(ex[pos])
            print(stack)
            stack.append(ex[pos2])
            print(stack)
            if stack[pos] > stack[pos2]:
                stack[pos], stack[pos2] = stack[pos2], stack[pos]
                print(stack)
            pos = pos + 2
            pos2 = pos2 + 2
```

I know it's not efficient, but it is based off code i made for a bubble sort which does

```
 go = True
    add = 0
    while go == True:
        for i in range(len(ex)-1):
            if ex[i] > ex[i+1]:
                go = True
                ex[i], ex[i+1] = ex[i+1], ex[i] #flips the numbers in the list
                print(ex)
                add = add + 1
    if add >= len(ex):
        go = False
```

EDIT
I have changed it drastically, but there is still a problem. It only swaps the values once, even if it needs to be swapped multiple times to be in the right place. Here is the code

```
pos = 0
    while pos < len(ex)-1:
        for i in range(len(ex)-1):
            stack.append(ex[i])
            print(stack)
            if stack[i-1] > stack[i]:
                stack[i-1], stack[i] = stack[i], stack[i-1]
                pos = pos + 1
            else:
                pos = pos + 1
```

Comment: Take a paper and analyze your code. You'll definitely get to see where you are going wrong and its clearly a big mistake.

Comment: As @hashcode55 mentioned, you can either analyze on paper, or print the values of your variables until you can see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare ex[pos] with ex[pos2] then you append the right element first :

```
if ex[pos] > ex[pos2]:
     stack[pos].append(ex[pos2])              
else stack[pos].append(ex[pos])
print(stack)
```

Comment: I have tried adding this but it gives me an error. stack[pos].append(ex[pos])

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Jeff its because you are never setting `go` to false.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pseudo code for a classic insertion sort from https://visualgo.net/sorting a great resource for learning sorting algorithms:

```
mark first element as sorted
for each unsorted element
  'extract' the element
  for i = lastSortedIndex to 0
    if currentSortedElement > extractedElement
      move sorted element to the right by 1
    else: insert extracted element
```

And here is how you could implement insertion sort in python:

```
def insertion_sort(l):
  for i in range(1, len(l)):
    j = i-1 
    key = l[i]
    while (l[j] > key) and (j >= 0):
      l[j+1] = l[j]
      j -= 1
    l[j+1] = key
  return l
```

Once you understand the basic insertion sort you should be able to understand where you went wrong in your implementation in that you are not properly storing `stack[pos]` in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for this, but we're supposed to be doing this without looking at pre-made code. We're allowed to ask for help, but since it's the weekend (so i can't ask my teacher), and none of my friends are able to help, i taught here would be a good place to try.

Comment: Ok I understand... Ignore the second code block, but I am sure your teacher would allow you to check out that visual algo site since it is pseudo code (how an insertion sort works at the high level in any programming language). And will really help you understand how it works in more than a superficial level since it shows you what is happening at each stage.